# How to use javascript AJAX response to create table dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am working on javascript.
I have some API calls(Using Ajax) in my code.
There is a button in my UI[image]

on click of this button I am making some API call using AJAX and displaying below HTML UI:
[image]

In the table above there are 2 rows. Now if I close this popup and then again click on **User Dashboard** button it will append those 2 rows again in the table. I dont want to append those rows again.

My code to form table using AJAX response looks like below:

```
getUserAccountDetailsCallback : function(userid, appid, response){

          if(response != "")
          { 
              var res = JSON.parse(response);

              var totalNoOfApps = document.getElementById('totalSites');
              var totalNoOfSubscriptions = document.getElementById('totalSubscribers');
              totalNoOfApps.innerHTML = res.totalNoOfApps;
              totalNoOfSubscriptions.innerHTML = res.totalNoOfSubscriptions;


              if(res.subscriptionsForCurrentAppId.length > 0){

                  for(var i = 0; i < res.subscriptionsForCurrentAppId.length; i++){

                      var td1=document.createElement('td');
                      td1.style.width = '30';
                      td1.innerHTML=i+1;
                      var td2=document.createElement('td');
                      td2.innerHTML=res.subscriptionsForCurrentAppId[i].gatewayName;
                      var td3=document.createElement('td');
                      td3.innerHTML=res.subscriptionsForCurrentAppId[i].priceCurrencyIso;
                      var td4=document.createElement('td');
                      td4.innerHTML=res.subscriptionsForCurrentAppId[i].amountPaid;

                      var date = new Date(res.subscriptionsForCurrentAppId[i].subscribedDate);
                      date.toString();

                      var td5=document.createElement('td');
                      td5.innerHTML=date.getMonth()+1 + '/' +date.getDate() + '/' + date.getFullYear();//res.subscriptionsForCurrentAppId[i].subscribedDate;
                      var td6=document.createElement('td');
                      td6.innerHTML=res.subscriptionsForCurrentAppId[i].transactionId;
                      var td7=document.createElement('td');
                      td7.innerHTML=res.subscriptionsForCurrentAppId[i].active;

                      var tr=document.createElement('tr');
                      tr.appendChild(td1);
                      tr.appendChild(td2);
                      tr.appendChild(td3);
                      tr.appendChild(td4);
                      tr.appendChild(td5);
                      tr.appendChild(td6);
                      tr.appendChild(td7);

                       var table = document.getElementById('tbl');

                      table.appendChild(tr);
                  }

              }

          }
      }
```

Please help. Where I am doing wrong.

Comment: You can delete tr's from table after close or before appending new. 
Or rewrite data in exist tr except of append new.

Comment: @Sojtin can you suggest me at code level ?

Answer (score 0):

1. add thead and tbody
   `<table>`
   `<thead><tr><th>#</th><th>Gateway.....</tr></thead>`
   `<tbody id="tBodyId"></tbody>`
   `</table>`
2. remove the content of tbody before appending

like this:

```
var tBody = document.getElementById("tBodyID");
while (tBody.firstChild) {
  tBody.removeChild(tBody.firstChild);
}
if(res.subscriptionsForCurrentAppId.length > 0){
```